# Wrong double calculation in C?

Tags: c, double

I am using DevC++ 4.9, running on WinXP SP3 (32bit), here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double value;

    int i;

    printf("Enter double: ");
    scanf("%lf", &value);
    i = value*100;
    printf("double: %lf\n", value);
    printf("int: %d\n", i);

  system("PAUSE");  
}
```

I have entered different values and here are the results:

Test 1:

[image]

Test 2:

[image]

Test 3:

[image]

Why Test 1 and Test 2 displayed different results??

Comment: I'd suspect this is just a peculiarity of how a float is stored, and how it can be approximated as an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to floating-point round-off:

What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic:
 http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

`3.07` cannot be exactly represented in binary. In your case, it's being rounded to slightly less than `3.07`, therefore `100 * 3.07` is evaluating to `306.9999999...`, which is truncated to 306.

Same applies to `3.05`. But `3.06`, is rounded slightly up. So `100 * 3.06` correctly shows up as 306.